# SQL Server 2005 and VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

Guys please bear with me here, I've started using this blog to learn visual basics, I seriously want to learn and so far it been helping me a lot. Thank You everyone...

Now my question goes like this:.

Saying I have data in the SQL Server 2005 database and I want to retrieve data from the SQL table and display it on the textbox or listbox. I want to select Faculty_ID,Faculty_Name,F_Description from Faculty table and display these data on the textbox or listbox. And let's say I have my connection working just fine, I just need a statement to retrieve data from SQL table and display it on the textbox.

How do I do that? Please bear in mind you're helping the most stupiest, dumbest guy ever.

Thank You in Advanced!!!!!.

Comment: A bit too vague, posting table structures and what your goal is here with this application might help.

Comment: the answer seems to be IN the question - the statement to get that data is `select Faculty_ID,Faculty_Name,F_Description from Faculty`..or are you asking HOW to post it to SQL and get the data back?

Comment: Basic understanding needed --> This is not a blog AND you should know how to make a select statement if you are using SQL.

Comment: @HoganNot every person have a clear understanding about VB.NET just like how you do. I'm seeking for help NOT to be criticised, if someone cannot help, the person would just keep quiet!!!.

Comment: @Plutonix, I do understand the select statement but now my question is how do I display the selected data from the table into a textbox or listbox, I don't know if I'm clearer.

Comment: Query the data using a **DataAdapter** or **Command**. Then either **bind** the data or update the control using it's **text** property.

Answer (score 0):

Repeaters are usually used to display data.  Below is an example of a repeater.  On the back end you can bind it to a list.  I'd suggest making your own data structure and then binding it to that.  By binding I mean, `repeaterID.Datasource = yourDataObject` and then `repeaterID.Databind`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="fieldList" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="1" width="75%">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <b>Object Field 1</b>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <b>Object Field 2</b>
                    </th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id='<%#Eval("") %>'>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="obj1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SQLObjectFieldRelName1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="obj2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SQLObjectFieldRelName2") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Text boxes and list boxes going to be less commonly used for any dataset.  You'd only really use them for a string or some text.  If that's what you want to do then I'd manufacturer your string in your code behind and set your textbox text to it.